# trying to use url friendly with function and htacess issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

This is my folder project inside htdocs:

[image]

In this index.php I have this include to include my /tpl/index.php:

```
<?php getHome(); ?>
```

Then I have my tpl folder:

[image]

But when I acess my *localhost/projet/*, Im getting some errors and my *httpl://localhost/project/tpl/index.php* its not including, so my `<?php getHome();?>` its not working.

**The errors Im getting:**

**Notice:** Undefined index: url in F:\Xampp\htdocs\projeto\dts\get_functions.php on $url = $_GET['url'];

**Warning:** include_once(../dts/bd_con.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in F:\Xampp\htdocs\projet\tpl\index.php

**Warning:** require(../dts/out_func.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in F:\Xampp\htdocs\project\tpl\index.php on line 3

Im trying use this function below, if the file that we write exists in my tpl foder it will include that file, else it will show the page not found 404 error.

```
function getHome(){
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $url = explode('/', $url);
    $url[0] = ($url[0] == NULL ? 'index' : $url[0]);

        if(file_exists('tpl/'.$url[0].'.php')){
             require_once('tpl/'.$url[0].'.php');
        }elseif(file_exists('tpl/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'.php')){
             require_once('tpl/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'.php');
        }else{
             require_once('tpl/404.php');
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are basing includes on a get paramater called "url" (via `$_GET['url']`).  But you do not have any get params in the URL so it is failing.  The error messages say that quite clearly:

"Undefined index: url in F:\Xampp\htdocs\projeto\dts\get_functions.php" means that there is no get param called url so nothing is defined for `$_GET['url']`

It is then going in to tpl/index.php but something from there is trying to incldue files which are not present on the disk.  It even gives line numbers in the tpl/index.php file to check.

I would add that including files directly based on URL paramters like that is pretty insecure.  Depending on the file permissions they could get anything on your disk with enough `../` in the get param.